# Watchkit space between groups

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacegroup

I have two groups, one below the other, and I see a space between the bottom of the first and the top of the second: [Here's my scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apjjab0koz3szub/Scene.png?dl=0) and [here's the simulator screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrtpir1f5tkkkg7/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot.png?dl=0).

I tried modifying the group spacing property, but it doesn't seem to work.
Please advise how can I eliminate the space between them.
Thanks!

Comment: I achieved removing the space, setting the Controller spacing property to 0, not the group spacing property.

Comment: you should post you comment as an answer and mark it as the correct answer so you can help other people. And re-host you screen shots on SO or Imagur

Comment: Sorry, downvoting as image links are no longer valid ☹️